# Python 3.x - how do get the values of the left column of a string

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.3

I am trying to write a program that will print the values from the left column of a string.

This is what I have so far:

```
str = '''Dear Sam:
From Egypt we went to Italy, and then took a trip to Germany, Holland and England.
We enjoyed it all but Rome and London most.
In Berlin we met Mr. John O. Young of Messrs. Tackico & Co., on his way to Vienna.
His address there is 147 upper Zeiss Street, care of Dr. Quincy W. Long.
Friday the 18th, we join C. N. Dazet, Esquire and Mrs. Dazet, and leave at 6:30 A.M. for Paris
on the 'Q. X.' Express and early on the morning on the 25th of June start for home on the S. S. King.
Very sincerely yours,
Signature of writer'''

splitstr = list(str)
while "True" == "True":
    for i in splitstr:
        left_column = splitstr[0:1]
        print(left_column)
        break
```

The output is:

```
["D"]
```

I'm still in the process of figuring it out, but I do know that I need a while loop and possibly a for loop. I know the break will make the program end right after it gets its value; I put it there because the program would just keep on going. But besides that I'm totally stumped.

Comment: `while True:` would be more concise and to the point..

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`; that masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `list(str)` you split the string into individual characters. This happens because strings are sequences too.

To split a string into *separate lines* use the [`str.splitlines()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
for line in somestring.splitlines():
    print line[0]  # print first character
```

To print the first *word* of each line, use `str.split()` to spilt on whitespace:

```
for line in somestring.splitlines():
    print line.split()[0]  # print first word
```

Or a little more efficiently by splitting only once:

```
for line in somestring.splitlines():
    print line.split(None, 1)[0]  # print first word
```

Comment: Excellent. :3 Just wondering if there was anyway to do it without the splitlines() method? I'm assuming that without that method you have have to have some kind of crazy super nest.

Comment: What are you trying to do then? You can use list comprehensions, and/or split on the `\n` character instead of using `.splitlines()`, but you don't change the need for some kind of loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier:

```
st='''Dear Sam:
From Egypt we went to Italy, and then took a trip to Germany, Holland and England.
We enjoyed it all but Rome and London most.
In Berlin we met Mr. John O. Young of Messrs. Tackico & Co., on his way to Vienna.
His address there is 147 upper Zeiss Street, care of Dr. Quincy W. Long.
Friday the 18th, we join C. N. Dazet, Esquire and Mrs. Dazet, and leave at 6:30 A.M. for Paris
on the 'Q. X.' Express and early on the morning on the 25th of June start for home on the S. S. King.
Very sincerely yours,
Signature of writer'''

print('\n'.join(e.split()[0] for e in st.splitlines()))  # first word...
```

or:

```
print('\n'.join(e[0] for e in st.splitlines())) # first letter
```